# Can't upload and save table rates in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-2.1.7

[image] this my csv sample file. I upload csv file and press save config  then show
[image]

[image]
this is my setting.How can i fix this.

Comment: please check system.log and exception.log so you can trace exact problem with it.

Answer (score 3):

- I think you use Condition Weight vs. Destination so admin panel Flat Rate select condition above screen short Price vs. Destination so please select Weight vs. Destination and upload csv file and check it

[image]

[image]